# Load Bootstrap CDN only if not is loaded before from another project

Tags: 8, theming

I want to load Bootstrap CDN but only if is not loaded before. How can I do this?

Today I'm loading on Libraries.yml like this:
[image]

And it works. But the problem is: in some cases the Drupal site already have another project that loads Bootstrap CDN and it is a conflict.

Is there a way to load Bootstrap CDN only if not exists?

Comment: `Drupal site already have another project that loads bootstrap` – It's unclear what that means. Drupal already ensures that a library only gets loaded once. So either tell `another project` to not load Bootstrap. Or know where in Drupal `another project` is loaded and on these pages try to prevent your Drupal's Bootstrap library from getting loaded (although I guess that's maybe not too trivial considering cache and/or aggregation). But yeah, first please edit your post and add info about where exactly the second Bootstrap is supposed to come from. And what conflict this creates.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

Attach the `modal-page-bootstrap` library as you are doing, and *don't* also load `bootstrap.js` in another way.

Don't worry about adding libraries multiple times to the same page. Drupal is smart enough to only load that library once, and at the right time and order.

The conflict will only arise if you are loading `bootstrap.js` some other way besides attaching a library. If this is the case, then as @leymannx says above you need to find where the extra bootstrap is coming from.

If the Bootstrap CDN is loaded by a script tag in a Twig template, just remove that script tag and only load the CDN via the library, allowing Drupal to keep track of it.

Another approach:

If `another_project` is a theme or contrib module, then it has probably already defined the Bootstrap CDN as a library. If this is the case, you could just attach that library wherever you need it to prevent conflicts. Take a look at the `another_project.libraries.yml` file to see the name of the library, and then load *that* library wherever you need it in your custom theme or module. Again, as above, this will allow Drupal to manage the library so that it will only be loaded once, and only where it is needed.

Note, however, that by doing so you will create a dependency on `another_project`. If you do this in a custom theme or module, then you should make that dependency explicit by declaring the dependency in your `info.yml`. Otherwise, if `another_project` is not present for any reason, you won't be able to load the library.